# Is there a way in Azure DevOps settings to create a Personal Access Tokens (PAT) equivalent that is not associated with a single user?

Tags: security, azure-devops, continuous-integration, settings, access-token

If I understand correctly, Personal Access Tokens (PAT) are associated with the user identity logged in (they are within User Settings afterall).

**Question**: For functional responsibilities that should not be associated with and reliant upon one individual team member's account (ex. automated systems deployments), is there a way to generate non-user contextual PATs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create non-user contextual personal access tokens. Personal access tokens are alternate passwords that user can use to authenticate into Azure DevOps.

You can create a service account with proper access, then generate PATs with proper scopes from this service account. So that all team members can use these PATs.

Comment: Secondary question. If a developer creates a 90 day PAT, uses it on a build agent installation, and then leaves the organization in 30 days... will the build agent break, or will it be able to continue using that PAT until its time expires?

Comment: The agent will continue to work, even if the PAT expired. The PAT is only used during the initial configuration of the agent. Check out [Server URL and authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#server-url-and-authentication)

Comment: Clear. Thank you. Question then is what credentials (if any) are being used by a build agent, if not a PAT?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, can you provide a link to where this can be done in C# please?